# .Net Core 3.1 Web Api Jwt Authorization returns 401.2 - Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, swagger

I have spent much time to solve Jwt Authorization problem. I have checked lots of article, but I could not solve this problem.

I am working on a web project by using Angular. I am working on jwt authentication and authorization, but it always returns 401.2 - Unauthorized.

When I test in Angular and by using Swagger, it always return 401.2 - Unauthorized as I said.

I am using jwt accessToken to authenticate identity.

**Here is my controller.**

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Creating album
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost("createalbum")]
        [Authorize]
        public virtual JsonResult CreateAlbum([FromBody] AlbumCreateApi model)
        {
            //if (model == null || model.Images.Count == 0)
            //    return BadResponse(ResultModel.Error("The upload process can not be done !"));

            Album album = new Album
            {
                Name = model.name,
                Place = model.place,
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime(model.date),
                Tag = model.tag
            };

            ResultModel albumCreateModel = _albumService.Create(album);

            if (albumCreateModel.Status)
                return OkResponse(albumCreateModel);
            else
                return BadResponse(albumCreateModel);
        }
```

**Here is my startup services optimization.**

```
using DevPlatform.Core.Infrastructure;
using DevPlatform.Framework.Infrastructure.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace DevPlatform.Framework.Infrastructure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents object for the configuring MVC on application startup
    /// </summary>
    public class DevPlatformMvcStartup : IDevPlatformStartup
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Add and configure any of the middleware
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">Collection of service descriptors</param>
        /// <param name="configuration">Configuration of the application</param>
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            //add mvc options and settings
            services.AddDevPlatformMvc();

            //add options feature
            services.AddOptions();

            //add Fluent Validation validator
            services.AddMyValidator();

            //add devPlatform Identity options
            services.AddDevPlatformAuthentication(configuration);

            //add devPlatform swagger
            services.AddDevPlatformSwagger();

            //add devPlatform swagger
            services.AddDevPlatFormSignalR();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure the using of added middleware
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="application">Builder for configuring an application's request pipeline</param>
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
        {
            //used for environment
            application.UseDevPlatformEnvironment();

            //used for exceptionhandler
            application.UseDevPlatformExceptionHandler();

            //used for static files
            application.UseDevPlatformStaticFiles();

            //used for authentication
            application.UseDevPlatformAuthentication();

            //used for authorization
            application.UseDevPlatformAuthorization();

            //used for swagger
            application.UseDevPlatformSwagger();

            //used for angular
            application.UseAngular();

            //used for signalR
            application.AddDevPlatformSignalR();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets order of this startup configuration implementation
        /// </summary>
        public int Order => 1000; //MVC should be loaded last
    }
}
```

**Here is my Authentication service method.**

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds authentication service
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">Collection of service descriptors</param>
        public static void AddDevPlatformAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            if (DataSettingsManager.DatabaseIsInstalled)
            {
                services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
                {
                    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                    options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;

                    //TODO: The identity might be configured.
                    //options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; 
                    //options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                    //options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);

                }).AddLinqToDBStores<int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppUserToken, AppRoleClaim>(new
                IdentityConnectionFactory(new SqlServerDataProvider(ProviderName.SqlServer, SqlServerVersion.v2017), "SqlServerIdentity", DataSettingsManager.LoadSettings().ConnectionString))
                .AddUserStore<LinqToDB.Identity.UserStore<int, AppUser, AppRole, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppUserToken>>()
                .AddUserManager<UserManager<AppUser>>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<AppRole>>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

                services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options =>
                 {
                     options.Cookie.Name = "Interop";
                     options.DataProtectionProvider =
                         DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Github\\Identity\\artifacts"));
                 });

                // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers

                JwtTokenDefinitions.LoadFromConfiguration(configuration);
                services.ConfigureJwtAuthentication();
                services.ConfigureJwtAuthorization();
            }
        }
```

**appsettings.json implementation for Jwt Configuration**

```
"JwtConfiguration": {
    "Audience": "localhost",
    "ClockSkew": 0, //Time in minutes
    "Issuer": "devplatformebapi",
    "Key": "iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH",
    "TokenExpirationTime": 1440, //Time in minutes. 1440 means a day.
    "ValidateIssuerSigningKey": true,
    "ValidateLifetime": true
  }
```

**Jwt Configure implementation**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace DevPlatform.Core.Security.JwtSecurity
{
    public static class JwtConfigure
    {
        public static void ConfigureJwtAuthorization(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthorizationCore(auth =>
            {
                auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            });
        }

        public static void ConfigureJwtAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        IssuerSigningKey = JwtTokenDefinitions.IssuerSigningKey,
                        ValidAudience = JwtTokenDefinitions.Audience,
                        ValidIssuer = JwtTokenDefinitions.Issuer,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = JwtTokenDefinitions.ValidateIssuerSigningKey,
                        ValidateLifetime = JwtTokenDefinitions.ValidateLifetime,
                        ClockSkew = JwtTokenDefinitions.ClockSkew
                    };
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Jwt Token service.

```
using DevPlatform.Core.Security.JwtSecurity;
using DevPlatform.Domain.Api;
using DevPlatform.Domain.Dto;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace DevPlatform.Core.Security
{
    public class TokenService : ITokenService
    {
        public TokenUserResponse GenerateToken(AppUserDto appUserDto)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, appUserDto.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, appUserDto.AppUserId.ToString()),
            };

            string accessToken = GenerateAccessToken(claims);
            string refreshToken = GenerateRefreshToken();
            var token = new TokenUserResponse
            {
                UserId = appUserDto.AppUserId,
                UserName = appUserDto.UserName,
                CoverPhotoUrl = appUserDto.CoverPhotoUrl,
                ProfilePhotoUrl = appUserDto.ProfilePhotoUrl,
                RegisteredDate = appUserDto.RegisteredDate,
                UserPosts = appUserDto.UserPosts,
                AccessToken = accessToken,
                RefreshToken = refreshToken,
                Expires = JwtTokenDefinitions.TokenExpirationTime.Ticks
            };

            return token;
        }

        public string GenerateAccessToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
        {
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var securityTokenHanlder = handler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Issuer = JwtTokenDefinitions.Issuer,
                Audience = JwtTokenDefinitions.Audience,
                SigningCredentials = JwtTokenDefinitions.SigningCredentials,
                Subject = claimsIdentity,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(JwtTokenDefinitions.TokenExpirationTime),
                NotBefore = DateTime.Now
            });
            string accessToken = handler.WriteToken(securityTokenHanlder);

            return accessToken;
        }

        public string GenerateRefreshToken()
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[32];
            using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**launchSettings.json implementation**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57064",
      "sslPort": 44393
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "DevPlatform.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is my Angular service for creating an album.**

```
  createAlbum(post: AlbumCreate): Observable<AlbumCreate> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders
      ({
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.authService.getToken,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":'*'
      });
    return this.httpClient.post(this.albumUrl + "createalbum", post, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        tap((data: any) => {
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Here is a screenshot when I test by using Swagger.

[image]

There are so many code blocks that I can not paste here. I would be very happy if someone could help.

If you would like to see the project, you can check here;

https://github.com/dogaanismail/DevPlatform

Comment: Have you publish it on iis?